# How Can I Control The Normal Pass In The Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to change the bump value inside the Compositor just like the other pass,like Direct indirect color glossy diffuse. 
i search on the manual i did not find how u combine  all pass with the Normal pass 
can some one help understand how i can use the Normal pass and what is it for ?

Comment: If you want to modify the bump or normal map you would do that for the material and not in the compositor. The normal pass is part of the data passes, not lighting passes and therefore it's not part of the image construction as depicted in the manual (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html?highlight=pass#combining).

Comment: thank you so much for clearing  this up